# Let $a$ be an real number with $a>1$. Let $x,y\ge a$ find a number $c$ such that $\left|\frac{x+y}{(x^2-1)(y^2-1)}\right|<c$

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to do a proof of uniform continuity and I am stuck on this step of the scratch work.
Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ show that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$ where $a>1$.
So far I have, for $x,y\in[a,\infty)$
$$\left|\frac{1}{x^2-1}-\frac{1}{y^2-1}\right|=\left|\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2-1)(y^2-1)}\right|=|x-y|\left|\frac{x+y}{(x^2-1)(y^2-1)}\right|.$$
So I am trying to get a constant in terms of $a$ that I can use for my $\delta$ in the proof. Any advice?

Comment: Hint: $ \frac{1}{x^2-1} < \frac{1}{a^2-1}$, $\frac{y}{y^2-1} < \frac{a}{a^2-1}$,

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise splitting into $\frac{x}{(x^2 - 1)(y^2 - 1)}$ and $\frac{y}{(x^2 - 1)(y^2 - 1)}$. We have $\frac{1}{y^2 - 1} \le \frac{1}{a^2 - 1}$, so let's examine $\frac{x}{x^2 - 1}$. If $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 - 1}$, then $f'(x) = \frac{-x^2 - 1}{x^2 - 1} < 0$ when $x \ge a > 1$. It is therefore decreasing, so $\frac{a}{a^2 - 1} \ge \frac{x}{x^2 - 1}$. Hence,
$$\frac{x}{(x^2 - 1)(y^2 - 1)} \le \frac{a}{(a^2 - 1)^2}.$$
The same can be said for $\frac{y}{(x^2 - 1)(y^2 - 1)}$ by a symmetric argument. Thus,
$$\left|\frac{x+y}{(x^2-1)(y^2-1)}\right| = \frac{x+y}{(x^2-1)(y^2-1)} \le \frac{2a}{(a^2 - 1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to show that $|f'(x)|$ is bounded on $[a,\infty)$. Then, uniform continuity follows from the MVT with $|f'(x)|\leq M$:

- $|f'(x)-f'(y)| \leq M|x-y|$

Now, you have

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac 1{x-1}-\frac 1{x+1}\right)\Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac 1{(x+1)^2}-\frac 1{(x-1)^2}\right)$$

Hence, on $[a,\infty)$ you get

$$|f'(x)| = \frac 12 \left(\frac 1{(x-1)^2}-\frac 1{(x+1)^2}\right)\leq \frac 1{2(a-1)^2}$$

Done.